# Returning empty string instead of the string 'null' vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a small website and am having difficulty displaying the empty string (blank space for if a customer doesn't have address 2 or address 3 information). A customer can create an account, and when they initially fill in their business address they can omit information that doesn't apply to them. Just like this:

```
business name
address 1
address 2
address 3
city, state, zip
```

Let's say a customer fills out their information as such:

```
Jonnys biz
123 Bear Lane
Seattle, WA 98119
```

In Vue, I believe the fields that were not used (i.e address 2, address 3) get sent to the backend as the string 'null'.

So on my website if a customer didn't fill out their address 2, address 3 info will look like this:

```
Jonnys biz
123 Bear Lane
null
null
Seattle, WA 98119
```

I want the address to look like this:

```
Jonnys biz
123 Bear Lane
Seattle, WA 98119
```

Here is some of the code I've modified.

```html
<v-col v-if="acctdetails.BusName" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center">{{acctdetails.BusName}}</v-row>
</v-col>
<v-col v-if="acctdetails.LocAdr1" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center">{{acctdetails.LocAdr1}}</v-row>
</v-col>
<v-col v-if="acctdetails.LocAdr2 === 'null' || 'Null'" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center"></v-row> //display empty string
</v-col>
<v-col v-else-if="acctdetails.LocAdr2" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center">{{acctdetails.LocAdr2}}</v-row>
</v-col>
<v-col v-if="acctdetails.LocAdr3 === 'null' || 'Null'" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center"></v-row> //display empty string
</v-col>
<v-col v-else-if="acctdetails.LocAdr3" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center">{{acctdetails.LocAdr3}}</v-row>
</v-col>
<v-col cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center" v-if="acctdetails.BusName">
    {{acctdetails.LocCity}} {{acctdetails.LocState}} {{acctdetails.LocZip}}

  </v-row>
</v-col>
</v-col>
```

Doing some testing, with this code, if address 2 is null, blank space is returned.

However, when I put in "Suite B" for address 2, it is still returning 'null'. I verified address 2 has a value because I manually inserted this data in the database table.

With this bit of code. If the customer enters in their data like this:

```
Jonny biz
123 Bear Lane
Suite B
Seattle, WA 98119
```

My page displays data like this:

```
Jonny biz
123 Bear Lane

Seattle, WA 98119
```

Comment: I don't know Vue.js, but I think `=== 'null'` should be `=== ''`

Comment: I thought so too, but the value saved within the database table is the string 'null' not NULL.

Comment: If you use v-model and send the form information to the backend how are the empty strings stored?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should look like this:

```js
<v-col v-if="acctdetails.LocAdr3 === ''" cols="12">
  <v-row justify="center"></v-row> //display empty string
</v-col>
```

When you use v-model you usually should bind your form inputs to empty strings

```js
const streetName = ref('')

<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="streetName" />
</template>
```